# ADB2C - How to change UI for password confirmation screen(In reset password flow)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I have created sign-in user flow with reset password user flow.
I have updated UI with custom UI in both the flows. When user click on 'Forgot password' link then user is seeing new UI for 'Reset password' user flow, but after email verification when user click on continue then user is seeing default UI as below.

Any one know how can I change this UI as well with custom UI.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add Custom page for Change password page also. I thin you have added Custom Page only for Forgot password page.

[image: Screenshot]